# Importing all the modules from a subdirectory

Tags: python

I'm trying to import all of the modules from a subdirectory with the next code in `__init__.py` in my_modules_folder:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob

def __reply_to_text():
    path = glob.glob(dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
    mod = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in path if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
    return mod

REPLY_TO_TEXT = __reply_to_text()

__all__ = REPLY_TO_TEXT
```

But it doesn't work. I'm importing REPLY_TO_TEXT in `__main__`.py but it doesn't work

Comment: just create your class in a file in a sub-directory and in the same sub-directory you create the __init__.py file and import your class file

Comment: Yeah, but that will require to use import over and over again

Comment: mmmm I use to do it,1 for each sub-folder and stop but in theory if you introduce them in system path variables you should be able to import them directly without any __init__.py file

Comment: You still didn't understood my question. I wanted to avoid spamming __main__.py with imports. Anyway, I posted an answer to my question that will explain how to use the code from my question.

Comment: Learn how to use `from module import *`

Comment: Yes, but I want to import all the modules from a folder :) See my answer below :P

Answer (score 0):

So:

The updated code is:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob
path = glob.glob(dirname(__file__) + "/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in path if isfile(f) and f.endswith(".py") and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

By default you can't import all the modules from a folder with `from my_folder import *` so the code above will make allow you to import all of the modules with `*`

So we have this dir:

```
> app_py
    >__main__.py
    > __init__.py
    >folder
        __init__.py
        example.py
```

Adding the above script in folder/**init**.py will allow you to import all the modules from that folder with `from app_py.folder import *` method that wasn't possible without the above script (You had to import each file every time)